# Container gets moved down when page resized

Tags: css, image, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

CSS:

```
.jumbotron{
    background: url("jumbotron.jpg") no-repeat center center;
    -webkit-background-size: 70%;
    -moz-background-size: 70%;
    -o-background-size: 70%;
    background-size: 70%;
    margin-top: 0 auto;
 }

.push-spaces {
    height: 550px;
}
.supporting {
    padding-top: 80px;
    padding-bottom: 100px;
}

.supporting .col {
    float: left;
    width: 33%;
    font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
    text-align: center;
}

.supporting .glyphicon {
    font-size: 4em;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="jumbotron">
    <div class="container-fluid push-spaces">

    </div>
</div>
```

Viewable on voiddevelopment.com

It seems as though whenever I shrink the page to the width of the phone, the image gets a ton of padding on the top and bottom, making it look like there's a lot of white space.

Looks like background-align automatically centers if you do not specify a value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You centered you `background-image` in the `center center`, it means that you `background-image` situated in the vertical and horizontal center of your block. So, the solution is just remove one `center`. Like this `background: url("jumbotron.jpg") no-repeat center;` - in this case you just center `background-image` in horizontal.

Comment: @AlesgaOleg I tried what you said but it doesn't seem to have made a difference. Updated voidevelopment.com with your suggestion